# PVC lubricant for pipe and fittings

Tags: plumbing

What kind of lubricant can I use on PVC pipe and fittings so that I can assemble and disassemble easily.  This is a stage made of PVC pipe that must be assembled and disassembled repeatedly.

Comment: This sounds like a poor design/material choice for the application. PVC fittings are not designed for "slip-fit" and will, in fact, jam quite throughly when dry-fit due to their shape.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to be able to easily assemble or dis-assemble or both? there is a problem that the lubricant will also make the stage easy to fall apart.

your choices:

- soapy water - will make it easier to assemble and remain hard to dis-assemble
- Silicone spray - is a good lubricant to use, since it is fairly non-reactive and effective
- Petroleum jelly - this is also good.. but will stick to everything and will get on your hands.

If its a clean environment and you are not worried about mess.. use the petroleum jelly, otherwise go for the Spray Silicon (electrical grade)

dont use things like wd-40, oil, glycerin based jelly since they will affect the plastic.

Comment: Assembly is easy, but disassembly is where I sometimes get stuck.

Comment: I would try out the silicon spray on one or two sample pieces. you could go with graphite powder but my concern is that you would probably end up needing lots. This is not really a common requirement, so you may require some trial and error.

Answer (score 1):

Plumber's silicone grease.

Silicone Faucet Grease helps reduce friction and provides long-lasting lubrication. The grease is water resilient and oxidation resistant.  Resistant to most harsh chemicals
Retains its consistency in temperatures from 40 to 400 F.

Answer (score 1):

My vote goes to a product called [Super Lube](http://www.super-lube.com/). It is PTFE (if you're DuPont you call it Teflon) (Polytetraflouroethylene) and is food grade. It works at a very wide range of temperatures.  It also works great for guns. I used it on the washers in a pressure reducing valve to keep them from deforming and to help seal them.  Works great!

Answer (score 1):

PTFE O-ring lubricant works ok on the threads of the Union but can make the outside slippery for a strap wrench so apply carefully

Answer (score -1):

I've been asking the same question for three days. The flexible coupling to join the two ABS section together is too tight to move it down and it stuck couldn't move it up fit into the other ABS pipe. I am searching for answer and came up with the answer for you and me. 
Try hand cream lotion like vaseline. I think, it's safe bet it won't damage the pipe. I don't like the soap solution, the bubbles, and air trap thing just don't feel right to me.